# measure column showing 1 as values instead of the actual values in Kylin SQL Query answer table

Tags: hadoop, kylin

The measure is of type column (not constant) and is bigint. I selected the measure from the dropdown corretly as well.
measure column returns 1 for all column values instead of actual values when querying the cube.
What could be the underlying problem? cube or model defining? or maybe data source attribute types?

Maybe I should create a lookup table with the fact table (which I am not doing so far)?

Thanks